Circulating supply wrong on solana fm?
I'm playing around with solana Token2022 [ExtensionType.TransferFeeConfig] (on dev-net).
but it seems circulating supply was different between solscan, explorer.solana and solana fm (I expect circulating supply is 1,000,000 token but only solanafm showing 100,000,000,000 supply).
https://solscan.io/token/sjta9cXsMtY9ax2ZSopcyJJhUwgfpuk6aaC3EzrrpLk?cluster=devnet
https://explorer.solana.com/address/sjta9cXsMtY9ax2ZSopcyJJhUwgfpuk6aaC3EzrrpLk?cluster=devnet
https://solana.fm/address/sjta9cXsMtY9ax2ZSopcyJJhUwgfpuk6aaC3EzrrpLk?cluster=devnet-alpha
not sure whether my code is wrong or there's a bug on solana fm?
any thought?



I just noticed the same. Yes, you are right the Solana FM is showing a wrong number without accounting the decimals and bigints that comes in between.
I checked the mainnet of both explorers and both of them are showing the correct values. See this:


But when I checked Devnet, this was the result. To confirm the correct one, I created token with supply 250 and decimal 5. As the input to mintTo from '@solana/spl-token expects the amount to be in  amount: number | bigint format, the input was given as 250_000_00 accounting 5 decimals and here are the results:


Here you can clearly see SolanFM's devnet is displaying the bigint as it is, not accounting the decimals.
